# Viewing error messages for RaiseError AMPscript function

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

We're using the [RaiseError AMPscript function](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/raiseerror/) to skip sending a Guided Send email to specific Subscribers based on a condition. For example:

```
RaiseError("Campaign Member already exists", true)
```

This works well and we see that there was an 'error' in the Status column on the Tracking > Sends page, but I can't find out where we can see the actual error message returned by the AMPscript function (for example, "Campaign Member already exists"). Does anyone know where this is available?

Comment: I had similar problem before and I couldn't find those error descriptions in SFMC UI as well. We bypassed it by creating separate Data Extension as error log with error description and subscriber information columns and used InsertDE() to populate it.

Comment: @MateuszBartkowiak struggling with this at the moment . The RaiseError needs positional parameters 3, & 4. What values do we provide here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All email tracking errors exist on 'the back end' (direct quote from a SFMC support specialist) and can only be accessed by SFMC support members.  There are a few different petitions to get this information available to users, but no movement yet that I am aware of.

I was told this is because most of the error messages are 'too technical for users to understand' and they want people to contact them to get an explanation.

In their defense, lately on major errors or issues, they actually have contacted me directly about it (with no action on my end) and helped me solve the issue. But on the average, it can be a PITA to not only contact them, but wait a few hours to hear back from them about an issue - especially on time sensitive sends.

As MBB stated in the comments, inserting to a Data Extension as an error log is the best option we have currently.